# Return x,y values of a 2D plot with mouse click

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, click, mplcursors

I'm plotting a simple image and like to get the x,y value, where I click with the mouse.

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = Image.open('points.jpg')

data = np.array(image)

plt.imshow(data)
plt.show()
```

[image: Image with 4 points]

So, I can navigate the mouse towards each point, click and at the end obtain a list with 4 x,y values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, for images to click on, 'png' is usually a more suitable format than 'jpg'. The compression used for 'jpg' colors can smear colors out.

[`mplcursors`](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is a small package that supports clicking (or hovering) on a plot. Standard it displays an annotation tooltip with coordinates. In your application showing an annotation tooltip seems useful. If not, you can suppress that behavior with `sel.annotation.set_visible(False)` and still receive the event with the coordinates.

The coordinates come in two flavors: `x` and `y` using the coordinate system of the axes, or an index `(i,j)` to indicate the pixel. With `imshow`'s `extent=` parameter you can flexibly set the desired ranges (default `x` and `y` go from 0 to the width and height of the image). The `x,y` at the center of each pixel are integer values. So, you can either append the `(i,j)` indices or the `(x,y)` to your list.

Some code to experiment:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors

image = Image.open('points.png')
data = np.array(image)
img = plt.imshow(data)

points = []

cursor = mplcursors.cursor(img, hover=False)
@cursor.connect("add")
def cursor_clicked(sel):
    # sel.annotation.set_visible(False)
    sel.annotation.set_text(
        f'Clicked on\nx: {sel.target[0]:.2f} y: {sel.target[1]:.2f}\nindex: {sel.target.index}')
    points.append(sel.target.index)
    print("Current list of points:", points)

plt.show()
print("Selected points:", points)
```